# Set Theory : $4$ Sets problem : Maxima and Minima in $4$ sets

Tags: combinatorics

There are $200$ students in a class. Each student is a member of at least one of the clubs Eagles, Falcons, Tigers and Pythons.

1. If each club has $100$ students, then the number of students who are
   members of all the four clubs is at the most ?
2. If each club has $120$ students, then the number of students who are members of at the most two clubs is at the least ?
3. If each club has $140$ students, then the number of students who are members of at least three clubs is at least?

Need help with this problem as I am unable to find out a way to solve this problem with literally no other information given. This could have been solved if some information can be given about some of the individual clubs but here nothing has been given. How to solve this and these types of questions? What should be the approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The questions seem straightforward. Can you try drawing venn diagrams? Some implicit constraints are that size of each set is positive, and number of students cannot exceed 200.

Comment: Hint for Q1 - $50< $ the number of students who are in all 4 clubs $< 100$, otherwise, the capacity of all clubs will be full, and the remaining 100 students would have no club to be a part of.

Comment: In the questions, I guess the numbers 100, 120 and 140 are the maximum capacity of the clubs and not the exact amount of members that we should assume, right?

Comment: From the language of the question I think it is exact number of members

Comment: @frabala : they are the exact number of members..

Comment: If you're having trouble drawing a Venn diagram for 4 sets here is an image: https://imgur.com/xRLPmC3

Comment: @frabala : there are some students who are members of all the 4 clubs... some students who are members of all the 3 clubs...some students who are members of all the 2 clubs and some students who are members of only one club...so the students who are members of all the 4 clubs will be counted 4 times...did you get my point?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan : too many variables are coming into the picture..

Comment: Dear @Ganit What are the source of your problems? I have seen atleast three of your questions, which are duplicate of ones already asked on MSE before. In one geometry problem, even the diagram were almost same (only scale ratio different). I'm not saying you may already be aware of it. But somewhere in the traffic of problem distribution, some questions are simply making it back to the site.

Comment: @cosmo5 : I am simply picking up these problems from the web for practicing as I am preparing for one of the competitive exams and sometimes while picking up problems pertaining to my exam I stumble upon questions which I can not solve even after multiple attempts and then I put those questions here for help from the community as I do not have tutor or mentor who could help me and this community is only I got where I can get my answers. Sorry for the repetitive questions asked. from the next time I will make sure that I check beforehand.

Comment: @Ganit That is good to know. You can either google wordy problems like this (maybe append the phrase "mathstackexchange" to the google search) or for mathy expressions you can use https://approach0.xyz/search/ Good luck on problem solving!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For part 1, consider some number of students who belong to all 4 clubs. This is at most 100, and at least 0. Now consider that the number of students in all 4 clubs is $100-x$ for some $x\geq 0$. Consider some club of the 4, say A.

If any of these x students of A, who are not members of all 4 clubs are members of other clubs, then they eat up numbers (summing to 100) of A as well as another club. Thus, the overall number of students would come down. Then for most number of students overall, we consider x to belong to just A.

Doing a similar exercise for all 4 clubs, we get $x$ members who are only in that particular club, and $100-x$ who are members of all 4 clubs. The total number of members is then $(100-x)+4x = 100+3x$. We are told this is equal to $200$, whence x is $\geq \frac{100}{3}$. Thus the number of members who are in all 4 clubs is at most $100-x = 66$.